# Login attempts on Wordpress while wp-login and wp-admin restricted by htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I receive a bunch of login attempt alerts on my Wordpress website dashboard so I decided to restrict access only to my IP adress.

Via htaccess in the Wordpress root directory

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xxx.xx.x
</Files>
```

And htaccess in wp-admin directory

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xxx.xx.x
```

When I test with other IP address I can see I'm blocked and can't access the login form.

Yet I continue to receive login attempts alerts.

My question, is there another entry for bots to log into my Wordpress dashboard that I need to lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a few time investigating, I discovered remaining login attempts were all made via blog editor apps.

The last openned gate to my dashboard login was the WordPress `xmlrpc.php` file,  a system that allows remote updates to WordPress from other applications.

So I decided to block it via .htaccess in Wordpress Root directory.

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

In addition to the previous rules as described in my own question
htaccess in the Wordpress root directory

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xxx.xx.x
</Files>
<Files xmlrpc.php>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 </Files>
```

And htaccess in wp-admin directory

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xxx.xx.x
```

Since then, I didn't receive any new suspicious login attempt on my Wordpress website Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't customize your website with a plugin that changes the login URL, I can only think of AMP, if you have set AMP, there's a different login page.

Comment: Thank you for your help but no AMP installed on this website. I installed a plugin to hide my login url but as it had no effect neither I deactivated it. Since your answer I deleted it but not sure it will have more effect.

Comment: Indeed it didn't help and after a week or so I received new login attempt alert. I finally found a solution as described in my own answer i m preparing. I upvote yours beacause it is always a good practice to delete unused plugins.